# Foreign language quotation marks with babel and csquotes on pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, babel, csquotes

I haven't been able to switch the quotation marks from Spanish to English in the document resulting from the MWE below. What, if anything, am I doing wrong or missing? And, yes, I've also tried by reversing the loading order of the `polyglossia/babel` and `csquotes` packages.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xifthen, ifpdf, ifxetex}
\ifxetex
\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
  \setotherlanguages{greek, english}
\else
\usepackage[greek, english, spanish, es-lcroman]{babel}
\fi

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Quoted text} \par
\foreignquote{english}{English quotation marks}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass the `autostyle=true` option to `csquotes`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xifthen, ifpdf, ifxetex}
\ifxetex
\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
  \setotherlanguages{greek, english}
\else
\usepackage[greek, english, spanish, es-lcroman]{babel}
\fi

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Quoted text} \par
\foreignquote{english}{English quotation marks}
\end{document}
```

By default `autostyle` is `tryonce`, so the quotation style is fixed after the first use.  Older `csquotes` had an option `babel`, but this has been replaced by `autostyle`, which will work with both `babel` and `polyglossia`.

Comment: That made it. The documentation doesn't seem to me particularly clear on the interplay between the `autostyle` options and the `foreignquote`command.

Comment: +1 I had the same problem and and agree with @Marcos.